# Software to plot graphs?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quadratics, math-software

I have an assignment to submit tomorrow and I've run out of graph paper. I need to plot quadratic equations. Do you know of any software using which I can plot line graphs? I'm not looking for an easy escape software in which if I write down the equation, the graph plots itself. I'm looking for a simple graphing software in which I can simply add values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic software for this is  Geogebra.

https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use python matplotlib. It's a python library for plotting 2D graph.
http://matplotlib.org
Check this link for documentation and installation instruction.

Comment: Great! Thanks I'll look into it and let you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DataMelt (http://jwork.org/dmelt). It has a [massive number of examples](https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=Function/1D) in Python and Java that plot functions. Here is a simple example:

```
from jhplot  import *
f1 = F1D("x*x+x+2", -10, 10)
c1 = HPlot("Example of  function")
c1.visible()
c1.setAutoRange()
c1.draw(f1)
```

It uses auto-range. It plots x^2+x+1 in the range -10 - 10. You can save it to EPS or PDF by appending this line:

```
c1.export("plot.eps")
```